# Add multiple controls to GridView column in windows form app

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I am adding two columns to `GridView` as below

```
            DataGridViewLinkColumn Editlink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
            Editlink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
            Editlink.HeaderText = "Edit";
            Editlink.DataPropertyName = "lnkColumn";
            Editlink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
            Editlink.Text = "Edit";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Editlink);

            DataGridViewLinkColumn Deletelink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
            Deletelink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
            Deletelink.HeaderText = "delete";
            Deletelink.DataPropertyName = "lnkColumn";
            Deletelink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
            Deletelink.Text = "Delete"; dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Deletelink);
```

Can I add both buttons under a same column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `DataGridView` control, you need to create your own usercontrol which contains two buttons
Next link show some example: [Multiple controls in a single DataGridView cell](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c28399bb-9d50-4a1e-b671-3dbaebb5cc69/multiple-controls-in-a-single-datagridview-cell)